# Uncover object type after it has been converted to string

Tags: json, ruby, types

I have a rather peculiar issue that I need to workaround, in Ruby.

I receive a list of values, say:

```
["foo", "0.0", "1", "{}", "[]"]
```

I want to uncover the actual type of each element, having no power over the fact that it has already been converted to a String type.

My initial attempt was to load each value individually using JSON deserialization, e.g.:

```
my_list.each |element| do
  puts JSON.load(element).class
end
```

however this has various caveats that mean it doesn't work quite right.

e.g. `JSON.load("0.0").class` will give me `Float`, but `JSON.load("foo").class` will, of course, bomb out.  My solution to this was to use a `try/catch` or `rescue` block for when it is an actual string, but it's not reliable as it breaks for custom classes (say I said `s = SomeClass.new, JSON.load("s")` it rescues as a string) and ends up as rather ugly code.

```
my_list.each |element| do
  puts JSON.load(element).class rescue String
end
```

Alas, the question I have to ask is, does there exist a way to effectively "unconvert" a string and find out the object type of whatever is contained within the string?

Apologies if this issue has been answered, I have searched at great length, and to no avail.  Right now, I feel like the answer is "no".

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can't distinguish them any more. `"1"` could be the number `1` or the string `"1"`. Same for the other values.

Comment: Where are you receiving these values from? Could you modify that source to instead send you JSON values, i.e. `["foo", 0.0, 1, {}, []]`? That would be *much* safer than using `eval`.

Comment: For that matter, are the values JSON strings or Ruby code? The below `eval` code will fail for values that are valid JSON but not valid Ruby.

Comment: Either JSON values or properly escaped strings, i.e. `["\"foo\"", "0.0", "1", "{}", "[]"]`

Comment: Unfortunately I can't control what the input format is.  They will all be objects converted in ruby that have just been hit with `.to_s`.  Strings will not be "escaped" correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your values are JSON strings, `eval` will fail. Use `JSON.parse`:

```
['foo', "0.0", "1", "{}", "[]"].map {|a| JSON.parse(a, quirks_mode: true) rescue a }
# => ["foo", 0.0, 1, {}, []]
```

The [`:quirks_mode` option](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON/Ext/Generator/State.html#method-c-new) enables parsing of single values, e.g. `0.0` and `1` (thanks Stefan).

It's generally a bad idea to use `rescue` without specifying an error class, though, so this would be better:

```
['foo', "0.0", "1", "{}", "[]"].map do |val|
  begin
    JSON.parse(val, quirks_mode: true)
  rescue JSON::ParserError
    val
  end
end
# => ["foo", 0.0, 1, {}, []]
```

Comment: `JSON.load` is meant for trusted data. You should use `JSON.parse` instead.

Comment: @Stefan That's a good point, but `JSON.parse('"0.0"')` returns `"0.0"` rather than `0.0`. Can you suggest a workaround?

Comment: `.map {|a| JSON.parse(a, quirks_mode: true) rescue a }` seems to work.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance folks, I will try run with this.  Man, I have a bucket load of Ruby still to learn.

Comment: Jordan, I am curious, how is the following array from your answer `['foo', "0.0", "1", "{}", "[]"]`, which values you claim to be JSON strings is different from this array of regular strings: `['foo', "0.0", "1", "{}", "[]"]` from my answer? (HINT: *they are identical*) And, which is more important for me to understand, how `eval will fail`? Are you saying that I have forged the output of `['foo', "0.0", "1", "{}", "[]"].map { |a| eval a rescue a }`? :) P.S. Not saying eval is a perfect solution here, just curious about `eval will fail` part.

Comment: If the only input OP will ever deal with is `['foo', "0.0", "1", "{}", "[]"]`, then OP should just hard-code the output.

Answer (score 2):

```
['foo', "0.0", "1", "{}", "[]"].map { |a| eval a rescue a }
#=> ['foo', 0.0, 1, {}, []]
```

To get the class:

```
['foo', "0.0", "1", "{}", "[]"].map { |a| (eval a rescue a).class }
#=> [String, Float, Fixnum, Hash, Array]
```

I am sure there might be corner cases, but if you have the data you have in your exemplary list it should work..

Comment: Well.  It's embarrassing that I couldn't figure that out :D

Comment: @Stuart you should only use `eval` for trusted data. _"I receive a list of values"_ sounds a bit uncertain in that regard.

Comment: Hi @Stefan, thanks for sharing your insight.  That is something I'm concerned about too, though I think I should be sort of safe.  I'll bear that in mind though, thanks!

Comment: @Stuart: As long as someone doesn't send you the value `"require 'fileutils'; FileUtils.rm_rf('/')"`, yes, that is "sort of" safe.